# FpML class generation gives error

Tags: programming

I am creating classes out of 5.1 FPML specification but I get following error.

```
Group 'Events.model' from targetNamespace='http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation'
has invalid definition: Circular group reference.
```

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Could you please update clean up your question and give more information about what you're doing (code, commands) with what software, etc? I'm pretty sure that in its current form your question will not get a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly StackOverflow question related to technical aspects of XSD. Please see  “[XSD.exe and Circular Group references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388844/xsd-exe-and-circular-group-references)”, ["removing circular group references from xsd schema file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831116/removing-circular-group-references-from-xsd-schema-files) and ["xsd.exe fails to handle circular group references"](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/637855/xsd-exe-fails-to-handle-circular-group-references)

Comment: It appears I was wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using xds.exe to autogenerate the class for deserializing this fpml. In my project I tried the same and had this issue. In the end I wrote my own class from scratch for this. 
a similar approach is mentioned [here](http://devio.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/dealing-with-circular-group-reference-errors-in-xsd-exe/) and is worth looking at. Else if you post your sample FPML I can try to repro and give you a class definition in C# / C++.